# Proof of whether the ships will collide?

Tags: geometry

My first sailing instructor had a rule of thumb that if another vessel appeared to be moving forwards across the background, then it would pass in front of our own vessel. And if it appeared to be moving backwards across the distant background, the it would pass astern (i.e., we would pass ahead of it). And if it wasn't moving across the background then a collision was on the cards.

My gut feeling is that I'm not so sure, and I suspect one would need to know more about the relative disposition of the background itself and so on. Is there a way to prove that the rule of thumb is true, or within what limits it is true? Ideally a way which can be understood by the non-mathematical sailor.

It should be said that the standard method of determining risk of collision is to look for a constant relative bearing for a vessel not on a parallel heading, and his rule of thumb avoided the need to actually take a sequence of bearings with a handheld compass.

Comment: If the background is truly distant, and none of you are in the process of changing speed or heading, then it checks out, as a rule of thumb should.

Comment: Depends on tides, river current as well. As @Arthur implied, if the coast is near, then it may not be such a good rule.

Comment: @copper.hat: Why does it depend on tides or river current? Assuming that these factors are more or less constant over an area that contains both ships, the _only_ thing that matters is that the background (not necessarily the coast) be sufficiently far away.

Comment: @TonyK: You are correct, but I'm presuming that since the two vessels are near they are in relatively confined space, so I'm assuming the background is relatively near. In open sea there is no background, so the operating range where (i) there is a background, (ii) it is sufficiently far away and (iii) there are two vessels close would seem to be fairly small...

Comment: @copper.hat: What does that have to do with tides and river current?

Comment: On a river in the appropriate current the other vessel could appear to be moving backwards against the background yet still be headed for collision. Maybe I'm over thinking this.

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes, I think you are. If the other vessel is moving with the current, then so are you.

Comment: Yes, but the other vessel will appear to move against the background regardless of its disposition with respect to the observer.